The question is in the title. I'm just wondering if Abū Mansūr al-Māturīdī believed in divine simplicity
The question is in the title. I'm just wondering if Abū Mansūr al-Māturīdī believed in divine simplicity.
I've been asking myself this question for a while and have read a few PDF's on the internet. Unfortunately I can't find anything about it because there are no English translations or at least very few. If anyone wants to help me, I would be very grateful, especially if you could send me a source or a quote.
God bless <3

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].  It would be helpful if you at least mentioned what you understand under "divine simplicity" so that potential answers can refer to your definfition.
